# How we can achieve singleton use of browser using Puppeteer, cucumber and JS (npm)

Tags: javascript, cucumber, puppeteer

Can anyone help me to setup the browser singleton in puppeteer with JS. As I am completely new in this world of JS and puppeteer.

Comment: Does this one help you move forward: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61277732/intergrate-puppeteer-tasks-into-one-single-task? I think a `'puppeteer+singleton'` Google search would be a better direction for you at this point as this kind of requests are not the best on Stack Overflow, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have used beforeAll for the same and finally able to achieve the same. Thanks